# Search a string from 500k entries in txt

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a .txt file which has about 500k entries, each separated by new line. The file size is about 13MB and the format of each line is the following:

`SomeText<tab>Value<tab>AnotherValue<tab>`

My problem is to find a certain "string" with the input from the program, from the first column in the file, and get the corresponding `Value` and `AnotherValue` from the two columns.

The first column is not sorted, but the `second` and `third` column values in the file are actually sorted. But, this sorting is of no good use to me.

The file is static and does not change. I was thinking to use the `Regex.IsMatch()` here but I am not sure if that's the best approach here to go line by line.

If the lookup time would increase drastically, I could probably go for rearranging the first column (and hence un-sorting the `second` & `third` column). Any suggestions on how to implement this approach or the above approach if required?

After locating the string, how should I fetch those two column values?

**EDIT**
I realized that there will be quite a bit of searches in the file for atleast oe request by the user. If I have an array of values to be found, how can I return some kind of dictionary having a corresponding values of found matches?

Comment: do you have access to an RDBMS?

Comment: Are there delimiters between the values on a line?

Comment: @KAJ: Consider `newline` as delimiters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many times do you need to do this search?
  Is the cost of some pre-processing on startup worth it if you save time on each search?
  Is loading all the data into memory at startup feasible?
  Parse the file into objects and stick the results into a hashtable?

I don't think Regex will help you more than any of the standard string options. You are looking for a fixed string value, not a pattern, but I stand to be corrected on that.

**Update**
Presuming that the "SomeText" is unique, you can use a dictionary like this

*Data* represents the values coming in from the file.
*MyData* is a class to hold them in memory.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Data = new List<string>() {
  "Text1\tValue1\tAnotherValue1\t",
  "Text2\tValue2\tAnotherValue2\t",
  "Text3\tValue3\tAnotherValue3\t",
  "Text4\tValue4\tAnotherValue4\t",
  "Text5\tValue5\tAnotherValue5\t",
  "Text6\tValue6\tAnotherValue6\t",
  "Text7\tValue7\tAnotherValue7\t",
  "Text8\tValue8\tAnotherValue8\t"
};

public class MyData {
   public String SomeText { get; set; }
   public String Value { get; set; }
   public String AnotherValue { get; set; }
}


[TestMethod]
public void ParseAndFind() {

        var dictionary = Data.Select(line =>
        {
            var pieces = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            return new MyData {
                SomeText = pieces[0],
                Value = pieces[1],
                AnotherValue = pieces[2],
            };
        }).ToDictionary<MyData, string>(dat =>dat.SomeText);

        Assert.AreEqual("AnotherValue3", dictionary["Text3"].AnotherValue);
        Assert.AreEqual("Value7", dictionary["Text7"].Value);

}
```

hth,

Alan

Comment: I am a little bent to use sort the search string column offline, and then perform searching on that. How many times to be searched? That rests with the user running the program.

Comment: Actually, your question on 'how many searches' took me back to the program to try. I editted my question with a bit of addition. Can you please help with that? Thanks

Comment: @Cipher My answer as posted gives you a dictionary you can use to look up the values.  Is something missing?

Comment: I meant that I have a `List<string>` with all the values to be searched. Can we search all all the values in the list from the text file, to return this similar kind of dictionary?

Comment: Do you have a List<String> containing all the 'SomeText' values or a List<string> containing the rows (SomeText, Value, AnotherValue) separated by tabs i.e. the lines from the file.  If you have a list of the SomeText values only, it is not useful, it needs association with the other values.  If you have a list of the lines then you can use the above code, just replace 'Data' with your List.  You can read all the lines from the file and parse them to a dictionary by replacing 'Data' with File.ReadLines(fileName).  hth

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with this code:

```
var myLine = File.ReadAllLines()
   .Select(line => line.Split(new [] {' ', '\t'}, SplitStringOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Single(s => s[0] == "string to find");
```

`myLine` is an array of strings that represents a row. You may also use `.AsParallel()` extension method for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstFoundLine = File.ReadLines("filename").FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("string"));
if (firstFoundLine != "")
{
    char yourColumnDelimiter = '\t';
    var columnValues = firstFoundLine.Split(new []{yourColumnDelimiter});
    var secondColumn = columnValues[1];
    var thirdColumns = columnValues[2];
}
```

`File.ReadLines` is better than `File.RealAllLines` because you won't need to read the whole file -- only until matching string is found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Comment: Can the time be decreased if I sort the `first column` data?

Comment: It depends. If you will load all data to the memory then search will be faster on sorted data. However it may take too much time to load data, so that optimization won't be worth it.

Comment: I realized that there will be quite a bit of searches for atleast one request by the user from the program. Can you elaborate the in-memory apprach as well for the sorted first column data?

Answer (score 0):

Parse this monstrosity into some sort of database.
SQL Server/MySQL would be preferable, but if you can't use them for various reasons, SQLite or even Access or Excel could work.
Doing that a single time is not hard.
After you are done with that, searching will become easy and fast.

Comment: Even if I sort the first column in this file, can you inscribe the preferred approach for searching?

Comment: What I suggested is importing the data into a database file, not sorting the first column. No matter how well you optimize your search, it still will never match a real database.

Comment: P.S. I have forgot about it before - but a better option than Access and SQLite is SQL Server Express, which is client-deployable, and doesn't require running any software on the client, while giving you access to advanced features such as full text search, which is exactly what you need for speeding up your search.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetLines(inputPath).FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Split(",")[0]=="SearchText")

private static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(string inputFile)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),inputFile);
    return File.ReadLines(filePath);
}
```